# How to get the VS 2019 installed location by c# program?

Tags: c#, registry, visual-studio-2019

how to get the VS2019 Preview installed path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional) from registry or some other way in C#?

Please suggest the way to do it.

Comment: Did it install an updated version of [VSWhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere)? Or you might be able to use the current version with a `-prerelease` parameter. Also see [this documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/02/25/vswhere-available/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Instead of using VSwhere.exe ,do we have any other way to do this?

Comment: You could look on GitHub at the source code for VSWhere, it should be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the Argument to VsWhere.exe -Version [16.0,17.0) -prerelease

It will return the installationPath of VS2019

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio setup configuration API for discovering instances of Visual Studio 2017 and newer: [Visual Studio Setup Configuration Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples).